# Retrieving the last billing cycle using shopify graphQL

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

Is there a way in shopify graphQL to determine the total number of a billing cycles the subscription contract has ?

I've tried the following query but it requires either billingCyclesDateRangeSelector or billingCyclesIndexRangeSelector, since I do not have the value of max billing cycle I do not have idea about the max date range or max index

```
  subscriptionBillingCycles(contractId: "") {
    nodes {
      cycleIndex
      cycleEndAt
    }
  }
```

Comment: form the API documentation it seems you can not get the list of Cycles, you can query `subscriptionContracts` and then you can pass `contractId` and get details.
means you have to do loop